# Eliminar caracteres especiales de un string c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, regex, google-drive

Tengo un proyecto en `c# asp.net` en el cual tengo que subir archivos a Google Drive a través de su API.

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk

El problema es que no me sube algunos archivos porque contienen caracteres especiales.

Quisiera saber de que forma puedo eliminar esos caracteres de la forma mas eficiente.

Por lo que pude investigar la mejor forma seria usar `Regex` pero no tengo conocimientos en expresiones regulares.

Los caracteres admitidos son los siguientes:

Letras `A-Z`, numeros `0-9`, y los caracteres `.!@$%^&*()-_/`

Desde ya muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: No soy experto en regex, pero prueba algo como `[a-zA-Z0-9_.!@$%^&*()\-\/]+`

Comment: @Pikoh [En efecto](https://regex101.com/r/iBzEXY/1) y [para .NET](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b%5cw.!%40%24%25%5e%26*%28%29%5c-%5c%2f%5d%2b&i=archivo1%0d%0aarchivo%401%0d%0a%28archivo2%402-6-2019%29%0d%0a1234archivo04-10-2019%0d%0a-------%2f%2f%2f%2f%2f%2f3%0d%0a!6f220xdeadbeef) :).

Comment: Utilizando las expresiones que proporcionaron en los comentarios anteriores, solo que daria realizar el reemplazo de los caracteres no adminitos. Por ejemplo: `string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"[^\w\s.!@$%^&*()\-\/]+", "");`

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa efectivamente, como bien dices si lo que se quiere es sustituir los demas caracteres hay que añadir el `^`. Creo que tu comentario podría ser una respuesta

Comment: Solo como referencia, podrias mirar el [tour] para saber como funcionamos?? gracias!!!!

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa, muchas gracias tu respuesta me funciono a la perfección.
No se como marcar la respuesta como correcta ya que no me da la opcion.

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa, quizás podrías agregar tu comentario como respuesta para que OP lo pueda aceptar

Comment: Agrego respuesta del usuario @OrlandoDeLaRosa como wiki de comunidad. bumandijo, puedes marcarla como aceptada. Saludos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prueba con lo siguiente:

```
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"[^\w\s.!@$%^&*()\-\/]+", "");
```

Con corchetes especificamos una serie de valores que puede tener un caracter. Si dentro de los corchetes se empieza por `^` entonces la negación de lo que hay dentro.

Así pues estamos montando esta expresión: `[^UNA_SERIE_DE_CARACTERES_ADMITIDOS]`

Por otra parte, el `+` es un quantificador y significa `1 o más veces de lo anterior`